# Парковка другого домена в GoDaddy

Tags: хостинг

Я с утра не могу парковать свой домен на GoDaddy хостинг. Есть IP адрес хостинга, но при посещении пишет "Ваш сайт готовится". Помогите, очень прошу

Comment: Скажите имя вашего сайта и хостера.

Comment: www.nic.ru -> orkhanalizade.com(domain)Хочу в GoDaddy хостинг привязать

Comment: я вижу у вас все уже показывается.

Comment: Ну, привязка же к неймсерверам не моментальная! Вплоть до нескольких дней бывает!